# Why Isn't My Dispatcher Displaying my Status Message?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I am trying to display a status message when the delete operation starts, something like `Deleting Items...` so the user knows what's going on.  I have a `DeleteManager` class that handles the display of messages when deleting any POCO:

```
public class DeleteManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IStatusMessageService _status;
    private readonly string _objectInstanceName;
    private readonly string _objectTypeName;
    private readonly string _singularFormat = "Are you sure you want to delete this {0}?";
    private readonly string _pluralFormat = "Are you sure you want to delete these {0}?";
    public readonly bool Confirmed;
    private bool _multipleItems;
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays status messages and performs confirmation for deleting an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status">the instance of IStatusMessageService that will display messages</param>
    /// <param name="objectInstanceName">The name of the instance of the object to delete</param>
    /// <param name="objectTypeName">The type of object to delete - specify the plural if needed. </param>
    /// <param name="multipleItems">Whether or not there are multiple items, to use plural strings.</param>
    public DeleteManager(IStatusMessageService status, string objectTypeName, string objectInstanceName = null, bool multipleItems = false)
    {
        _dispatcher = Wpf.Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        _status = status;
        _objectInstanceName = objectInstanceName;
        _objectTypeName = objectTypeName;
        _multipleItems = multipleItems;

        Confirmed = ConfirmDelete();

        if (Confirmed)
        {
            var message = _multipleItems
                ? string.Format("Deleting multiple {0}...", _objectTypeName)
                : string.Format("Deleting {0}: {1}...", _objectTypeName, _objectInstanceName);

            // this is the message that doesn't display... dunno why
            _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _status.Status.StaticMessage(message)));
        }
    }

    private bool ConfirmDelete()
    {
        var format = _multipleItems
            ? _pluralFormat
            : _singularFormat;

        var message = string.Format(format, (_objectInstanceName == null)
            ? _objectTypeName
            : string.Format("{0} : \"{1}\"", _objectTypeName, _objectInstanceName));

        return (bool)_dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Func<bool>(() => 
            // StatusControl is a modal window
            StatusControl.ConfirmMessage("Delete Warning", message)));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Confirmed)
        {
            var message = _multipleItems
                ? string.Format("Multipe {0} Deleted.", _objectTypeName)
                : string.Format("{0} Deleted: {1}.", _objectTypeName, _objectInstanceName);

            // THIS message displays just fine.  
            _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _status.Status.InfoMessage(message)));
        }
    }
}
```

... and it's being used like this:

```
var deleteId = Poco.Id;

using (var delete = new DeleteManager(StatusMessageService, "Poco", Poco.Name))
{
    if (delete.Confirmed)
    {
        var success = _dataProvider.DeleteCurriculum(deleteId);
        if (success)
        { EventAggregator.GetEvent<DeletedNotification>().Publish(deleteId); }
    }
}
```

The `InfoMessage()` call in `Dispose()` displays just fine, but the `StaticMessage()` call in the constructor *never* displays... even if I change it to use InfoMessage() instead...  I cannot determine why, nor how to fix it.

Comment: Can you try delaying it to something like this `_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _status.Status.StaticMessage(message)), DispatcherPriority.Background);`

Comment: You've got your arguments backward, but I knew what you meant - altering the priority "helped..." - the message displays, but not until *after* the success/completed message.

Comment: My suggestion is to not tie your control to the manager, implement MVVM with the dialog and you don't have to worry about this and you control it by Onpropertychanged